# 1: 32 The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: ruby, xml

I am completely unfamiliar with `xml`. For a project however, I had to export some data to an `xml` file. I ran it through a validator and googled the error, which of course brought me here. I've read other questions/answers and was unable to glean any insight to a fix/problem. 
I have an array of objects which I iterate over and create a hash of the attribute key/values pairs. I then use `Gyoku` to write to convert the hash to `xml` as it writes to the file. This is the snippet that writes to the xml file.

```
File.open("#{file}","w") do |file|
  queued.map do |att|
    temp_hash={last_name: att.last_name.capitalize, first_name: 
     att.first_name.capitalize,
     email: att.email, zipcode: att.zipcode, city: 
     att.city.split.map(&:capitalize)*' ',
     street: att.street, state: att.state, phone: att.phone}
     file.puts Gyoku.xml(temp_hash)
  end
end
```

This is the output to the `xml` file.

```
<lastName>G</lastName><firstName>Mike</firstName>
<email>myname@ymail.com</email><zipcode>83709</zipcode>
<city>Boise</city><street>4498 South Spring Ave.</street>
<state>ID</state><phone>(208)4568768</phone>
<lastName>D</lastName><firstName>Mike</firstName>
<email>anotheremail@ymail.com</email><zipcode>26508</zipcode>
<city>Morgantown</city><street>1129 Edinshire Dr.</street>
<state>WV</state><phone>(724)5555555</phone>
```

Not sure what `1:   32  The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed` means. Thank you in advance for any help with this.

Comment: An XML document must have a single root element.  Wrap your multiple elements with a single parent element in order for your XML document to be well-formed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XML document must have a single root element. Elements can't be implicit (unlike SGML), ergo, your root element is `lastName` (by virtue of being the first opening tag in the document). But, there are *two* `lastName` elements, wheres there can only be a single root element.

So, you either need to split your document in two, or introduce a separate root element.

Comment: would that be like when outputting to html or text or csv or w/e that I have a predefined "header" and *then* the bulk of the file?